# Is it possible to have nested transclusion in Angular using named slots?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have a simple dialog directive that uses optional multiple transclusion to include custom headers and footers.

```
<div class="dialog" ng-show="showing">
    <div class="dialog-header" ng-transclude="header">
        <span class="dialog-close" ng-click="hide()">&times;</span>
        <span class="dialog-title" ng-transclude="title">{{title}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog-body" ng-transclude></div>
    <div class="dialog-footer" ng-transclude="footer"></div>
</div>
```

And I have created several directives that encompass wizards or tools that I'd like to appear in a dialog (or somewhere else...it is modular, after all).  Here, I include the *query* directive.

```
<dialog dialog-title="Query" showing="query.active">
    <query></query>
</dialog>
```

I would like to nest the header or footer in the query directive, like so. Notice the dialog-footer element at the bottom.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span class="query-tab" ng-repeat="tab in query.tabs track by tab.id" ng-click="query.activateTab(tab)" ng-class="{active : tab.query.active}">{{tab.label}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="tab-section" ng-repeat="tab in query.tabs track by tab.id" ng-show="tab.query.active">
                <div class="query-results-table-container">
                    <table>
                        <tr><th class="query-header" ng-click="query.sort(tab.query.items, field)" ng-repeat="field in tab.query.fields">{{field.name}}<span ng-show="query.sortField == field" ng-class="query.sortAscending ? 'icon-arrow-up' : 'icon-arrow-down'"></span></th></tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in tab.query.items" ng-class="{even: $even}"><td ng-repeat="field in query.getFields(item.data, tab.query.fields) track by $index">{{field}}</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear-floats"></div>
    <dialog-footer>{{query.message}}</dialog-footer>
</div>
```

I want the dialog directive to recognize the named slot that is nested in the query directive, but it cannot.  Is it possible to transclude the dialog-footer element that is nested in the query element?  Is it possible to "exclude" (move an element outside of its parent) to get the dialog-footer element outside the query element so that the dialog element can recognize its named slot, and properly transclude it?

Is there a simpler solution to this that I'm not thinking about?

**I only include text in the footer element, as an example, but the content might be far more complex, and isn't really suitable for an attribute.

Comment: DId you see multiSlot Transclude example? : https://plnkr.co/edit/ZyCOqrgyV2fuoizvfE14?p=preview

Comment: @MaximShoustin No I hadn't see that example.  Thanks.  I think I understand well enough how to use multislot transclusion, my problem is that I want the named slot to appear in a nested directive.